# Taylor Series of a Product of Functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, taylor-expansion

The following is a problem I made to explore the Taylor series more deeply.  Say we have the definition
\begin{equation}
\frac{-1}{a} \partial Q(q) \partial Q(q) = M(q)    \hspace{20pt} (1)
\end{equation}
If I had a term
\begin{equation}
\frac{-2}{a} \frac{\partial Q(q) \partial Q(q)}{(p-q)^{2}} \hspace{20pt} (2)
\end{equation}
that I wanted to take the Taylor series of, I want to check if the two ways I think I can do this problem are correct and equivalent.  I will be trying to find the next term in the Taylor series in two different ways.

**Way 1:**
Use (1) immediately to yield
\begin{equation}
-2 \frac{M(q)}{(p-q)^{2}} \hspace{20pt} (3)
\end{equation}
Now taking the Taylor series of (3) to obtain the next term
\begin{equation}
-2 \frac{\partial M(q)}{(p-q)^{2}} \frac{(p-q)}{2!} = \frac{\partial M(q)}{(p-q)} \hspace{20pt} (4)
\end{equation}
which is the correct solution.

**Way 2:**
This next way is where my question stems from.  I will **not** use (1) first.  Thus I will take the Taylor series in the factor $\partial Q(q)$ immediately from (2)
\begin{align}
\frac{-2}{a} \frac{\partial(\partial Q(q) \partial Q(q))}{(p-q)^{2}} \frac{(p-q)}{2!} &= \frac{-1}{a} \frac{\partial(\partial Q(q))\hspace{1pt} \partial Q(q) + \partial Q(q)\hspace{1pt} \partial(\partial Q(q))}{(p-q)}\\ &= \frac{-2}{a} \frac{\partial^{2} Q(q) \hspace{1pt} \partial Q(q))}{(p-q)} \hspace{20pt} (5)
\end{align}
Which is also correct.  My main question comes from now applying (1) to (5).  Would the following be correct mathematically?  I assume that
\begin{equation}
\partial^{2}Q(q) \hspace{2pt} \partial Q(q) = \frac{1}{2} \partial\left(\partial Q(q) \hspace{2pt} \partial Q(q)  \right) \hspace{20pt} (6)
\end{equation}
So now (5) becomes
\begin{equation}
\frac{-2}{a} \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial\left(\partial Q(q) \hspace{2pt} \partial Q(q)  \right)}{(p-q)} = \frac{\partial M(q)}{(p-q)} \hspace{20pt} (7)
\end{equation}
where I applied (1) to obtain (7).  Would my thinking be correct that these are both equivalent ways of ending up with the final solution $\frac{\partial M(q)}{(p-q)}$?

Comment: What is $\partial$? How exactly do you get from (3) to (4)?

Comment: I took the Taylor expansion of the function $M(p)$ at $q$.